# How to calculate numbers from an axis in R plot

Tags: r

In my geophysics class, I need to make a plot of wavespeed vs depth. This looks decent, but I would have prefered to have the depth (on the y-axis) as positive numbers (i.e. 1 km depth rather than -1 km height as it is now). I know I could specify the labels manually, but can I somehow tell R to use the negative numbers (or mirror the Y axis so I plot it with positive numbers initially)

[image]

Comment: Could you gives as the data and show the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the axis labels to "mirror" the y axis. An example is:

```
x <- 0:10
y <- -10:0 # y is -10 to 0

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
# Left plot
plot(x, y, main = "Original", frame = FALSE)

# Right plot
plot(x, y, axes = FALSE, main = "Mirroring")
axis(1)
axis(2, at = y, label = rev(x)) # assuming x and y are the same length
```

[image]

Without a reproducible example, not sure if this will solve your specific issue, but should get you started!